# how to remove / hide 'featured image' option from side menu

Tags: images

I want to remove the menu item for featured images.  I do not want any featured images in posts, so I want to prevent my users from adding any.

How do I remove / hide the link to add a featured image from side menu.

WP 4.7.2

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your theme or parent theme, there's this line:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

If it's in your child theme, you can simply remove it. If it's in your parent theme, you can add this to your child theme functions.php file.

```
// in your Child Theme's functions.php    

// Use the after_setup_theme hook with a priority of 11 to load after the
// parent theme, which will fire on the default priority of 10
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_featured_images_from_child_theme', 11 ); 

function remove_featured_images_from_child_theme() {

    // This will remove support for post thumbnails on ALL Post Types
    remove_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    // Add this line in to re-enable support for just Posts
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_support